# What causes this 'interface not found' error in Sonatype Nexus 3.38.1-01 API testing?

Tags: api, nexus, sonatype

I get a problem when I test the interface in Sonatype Nexus.Image show the full info[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D7p7.png).Looking forward to help, tks

I downloaded the source code on github(https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public.git) but didn't find this interface, and then consulted chatgpt and found it was wrong.